# Equivalence of (M a >>= f) >>= g and M a >>= (f >>= g) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I have two Haskell functions that are equivalent.

```
triple :: Int -> Int
triple = do
  n <- id
  d <- (n+)
  (d+)

triple2 :: Int -> Int  
triple2 = (id >>= (\n -> (n+))) >>= (\d -> (d+))
```

The signature of `>>=` is `M a ->  (a -> M b) -> M b`, so the parenthesis are used to stress the relation ship `((Ma >>= f) >>= f2)` or `M b >> f2`.

However, this triple3 is also the same equivalent function as triple or triple2.

```
triple3 :: Int -> Int  
triple3 = id >>= (\n -> (n+) >>= (\d -> (d+)))
```

What is the logic behind these equivalences?

Comment: Downvote without any comments on what's wrong with the question? I didn't expect to see this kind of cowardice from a Haskell tagged question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This equivalence is the third of the [Monad Laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) and concerns itself  with associativity, so it is no surprise that `triple2` and `triple3` are equivalent. After all the  [`(->) r` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-645) obeys the monad laws. The third monad law states that

```
(m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

In your case, you have `m = id`, `f = \n -> (n+)`, and `g = \d -> (d+)`. To prove why this law holds, we need to look at the [definition of `(>>=)` for this monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-645). From this link, we get that

```
f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

To verify the third monad law with this definition of `(>>=)`, we'll use a couple rules:

- *Definition of `(>>=)`:* `f >>= k ≡ \ r -> k (f r) r`
- *Beta transformation:* [basically function application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Beta_reduction)
- *Function currying:* `(f x) y ≡ f x y`

Now for the proof:

```
(m >>= f) >>= g
  ≡ (\ r1 -> f (m r1) r1) >>= g                             (Definition of (>>=))
  ≡ \ r2 -> g ((\ r1 -> f (m r1) r1) r2) r2                 (Definition of (>>=))
  ≡ \ r2 -> g (f (m r2) r2) r2                              (Beta transformation)
  ≡ \ r2 -> g ((f (m r2)) r2) r2                            (Function currying)
  ≡ \ r2 -> (\ r1 -> g ((f (m r2)) r1) r1) r2               (Beta transformation)
  ≡ \ r2 -> ((\ x -> (\ r1 -> g ((f x) r1) r1)) (m r2)) r2  (Beta transformation)
  ≡ \ r2 -> ((\ x -> f x >>= g) (m r2)) r2                  (Definition of (>>=)) 
  ≡ \ r2 -> (\ x -> f x >>= g) (m r2) r2                    (Function currying) 
  ≡ m >>= (\ x -> f x >>= g)                                (Definition of (>>=))
```